Kotlin java.lang.AssertionError: numMsgsRcvd:1 should be less than numMsgsSent:1
I get an SQL error while I try to check if the table I am going to operate on exists or not. I am working with MSSQL, and I am just learning how to make this connection. When I first run, I get the message saying database connection successful. But when I try to make this check or anything else, I get the error below.
My dependencies and versions are:
[versions]
agp = "8.6.1"
androidxMaterialIconsExtended = "1.7.2"
hiltAndroid = "2.52"
hiltLifecycleViewmodel = "1.2.0"
kotlin = "2.0.20"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.2.1"
espressoCore = "3.6.1"
kotlinxCoroutinesAndroid = "1.8.1"
kotlinxCoroutinesCore = "1.8.1"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.8.6"
activityCompose = "1.9.2"
composeBom = "2024.09.02"
journeyappsZxingAndroidEmbeddedVersion = "4.3.0"
navigationCompose = "2.8.1"
kspVersion = "2.0.20-1.0.24"
mssqlJdbc = "12.8.0.jre11"
exposed = "0.54.0"
roomKtx = "2.6.1"
roomRuntime = "2.6.1"
roomRxjava2 = "2.6.1"
slf4jSimple = "1.7.30"

class DBRepository @Inject constructor() {

    private val url =
        "jdbc:sqlserver://[IP Address];databaseName=dbName;user=user3;password=password2;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=true"
    
    init {
        try {
            connectToDatabase()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("DBRepository", "Initialization failed: ${e.message}")
        }
    }

    private fun connectToDatabase() {
        try {
            Database.connect(url = url, driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
            Log.d("DBRepository", "Database connection successful.")
            println("Database connection successful.")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Database connection failed: ${e.message}")
            println("Database connection failed: $e")
            Log.e("DBRepository", "Database connection failed: ${e.message}")
        }
    }

    suspend fun ensureTableExists() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                transaction {
                    val tableExists = exec(buildString {
                        append("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Barcode'")
                    }) { resultSet ->
                        resultSet.next()
                    }
                    if (tableExists != true) {
                        exec(buildString {
                            append("CREATE TABLE dbo.Barcode (id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), barkodAd NVARCHAR(255), barkodYol NVARCHAR(255), parametreRef INT, durum BIT)")
                        })
                        println("Table 'Barcode' created successfully.")
                    } else {
                        println("Table 'Barcode' already exists.")
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("Error occurred while ensuring table existence: ${e.message}")
                println("Error occurred while ensuring table existence: $e")
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}


@HiltViewModel
class DBViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: DBRepository) : ViewModel() {

    fun checkIfTableExists() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                repository.ensureTableExists()
                println("Table check and creation (if necessary) complete.")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("Error: ${e.message}")
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}


FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: com.example.barcodescanningm3, PID: 5146
java.lang.AssertionError: numMsgsRcvd:1 should be less than numMsgsSent:1
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:6880)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.nextPacket(IOBuffer.java:6844)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.ensurePayload(IOBuffer.java:6816)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readBytes(IOBuffer.java:7168)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:953)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:943)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:1207)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:1193)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.readFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:983)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:947)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.-$$Nest$mprocessDataFromSocket(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:236)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:218)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1855)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3814)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:3402)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:3211)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1979)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1267)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion.connect$lambda$15(Database.kt:287)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion.$r8$lambda$mEHBWFmZQ2gRK5ZHcUc-r3aPdO4(Unknown Source:0)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.invoke(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion.doConnect$lambda$3(Database.kt:165)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion.$r8$lambda$M4UP17SW69mgZ60amKECb4ILQEA(Unknown Source:0)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion$$ExternalSyntheticLambda12.invoke(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManager$ThreadLocalTransaction.connectionLazy$lambda$2(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:138)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManager$ThreadLocalTransaction.$r8$lambda$t9ZtbVA_79RBbPMP0NEp6XRjTlU(Unknown Source:0)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManager$ThreadLocalTransaction$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.invoke(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManager$ThreadLocalTransaction.getConnection(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:163)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Transaction.getConnection(Unknown Source:2)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.Statement.prepared(Statement.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.Statement.executeIn$exposed_core(Statement.kt:79)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Transaction.exec(Transaction.kt:292)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Transaction.exec(Transaction.kt:269)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Transaction.exec(Transaction.kt:235)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Transaction.exec$default(Transaction.kt:223)
    at com.example.barcodescanningm3.data.repository.DBRepository$ensureTableExists$2.invokeSuspend$lambda$3(DBRepository.kt:41)
    
at com.example.barcodescanningm3.data.repository.DBRepository$ensureTableExists$2.$r8$lambda$k4755KZv3AIYPTdnxsj5WSbEMvs(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.example.barcodescanningm3.data.repository.DBRepository$ensureTableExists$2$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.invoke(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.inTopLevelTransaction$run(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:334)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.inTopLevelTransaction$lambda$10(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:381)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.$r8$lambda$Gk1vyoDXU27VaM6Az7NTZXYouWA(Unknown Source:0)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.invoke(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.keepAndRestoreTransactionRefAfterRun(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:389)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.inTopLevelTransaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:380)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction$lambda$4(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:289)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.$r8$lambda$aTLrtOoqP27z7BT_U8gXwZaruhU(Unknown Source:0)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.invoke(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.keepAndRestoreTransactionRefAfterRun(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:389)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:249)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:227)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction$default(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:226)
    at com.example.barcodescanningm3.data.repository.DBRepository$ensureTableExists$2.invokeSuspend(DBRepository.kt:39)
    at com.example.barcodescanningm3.data.repository.DBRepository$ensureTableExists$2.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
    at com.example.barcodescanningm3.data.repository.DBRepository$ensureTableExists$2.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:61)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:163)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source:1)
    at com.example.barcodescanningm3.data.repository.DBRepository.ensureTableExists(DBRepository.kt:37)
    at com.example.barcodescanningm3.viewmodel.DBViewModel$checkIfTableExists$1.invokeSuspend(DBViewModel.kt:17)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:111)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:99)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:811)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:715)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:702)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@58e0d7f, Dispatchers.IO]

I am not quite understanding the problem, so I have been trying to change everything. I changed the URL I am sending, I changed the operations, the way I used Couroutines, etc. But none of them worked. I think the solution is probably easy to find, but right now I got stuck.

Don't use microsoft jdbc in android, you're supposed to use an api endpoint. I recognize the issue though, i think it's something to do with ssl libs in android

Yes, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/427148/nummsgsrcvd-1-should-be-less-than-nummsgssent-1

I normally do that, but how can I achieve API type calls with MSSQL? Since it works with queries, documentation I read led me to use JDBC. How can I use API calls like you said? 
Or do you remember what I need to change in SSL libraries? @siggemannen

I mean, create a server/service running somewhere not on a phone that uses jdbc and fetches data. Call this server/service from the phone. Not sure there's a solution, but read that long github thread

i still cannot figure out sadly. I changed many libraries  but i still get the same problem

Did you create a webservice?

sorry for replying late, i fixed the issue by using jdbc:jtds:sqlserver and somehow that worked

I'm not sure why you are so stubborn, jtds is old and bad library, as i wrote, don't connect to sql server from android directly, it's just a bad idea. But anyways, just keep this in mind when you get in trouble in a couple of years/months

I understand your concern but this is not my decision, the company i am building this for is refusing to create a webservice for this. It would make my job much easier believe me but it is not my decision.

Thank you @KeremE. for posting your solution, it worked for me as well. There are plenty of valid use cases for connecting to SQL Server directly from Android where an extra middle man web service would be an unnecessary step and a headache to maintain. For instance, we use modified Android phones as warehouse UPC scanners and we just need to be able to perform some simple CRUD operations on a local network.
